# Virtual machine and viruses

Tags: kali-linux, vmware

I have a 1tb hdd and I have installed windows 10 on 600gb and the rest space, I have given to kali Linux. I want to install vmware in kali Linux and test Malware samples. So if the virus does something, will it affect the first my windows partition files because in kali file explorer I see both my windows partition (c and d) . Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a great deal wrong in your assumptions here. First, Kali Linux is for pen testing and forensics. While it does have some AV tools, it's pretty much Clam AV. Secondly, if you want to do Malware analysis, you'd need to install an operating system upon which the malware can act. Looking at Windows binaries on Linux is pretty pointless.

Comment: @DrDamnit he wants to run VMware on the Kali instance, presumably to virtualize other OSes like Windows.

Comment: @Sam - can you clarify please?

Comment: @DrDamnit what you said about malware analysis is untrue. A lot of reverse engineering of malicious windows binaries happens under Linux. people wrote wrappers to run windows' AV subsystem under Linux. You can natively execute PE32 thanks to wine. You typically want to inspect an infection by looking at a infected VM *from the outside*. Of course, having an affectable system is important, but I'd argue that the Windows VM is a *tool* here, much like GDB. You set up both from within your Host OS (which can be pretty much any OS that can run VMs).

Answer (score 1):

So long as you use VMware with care it should prevent malware from affecting your host machine. That is unless the malware has a [VM to host escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine_escape) exploit, but they are relatively rare.

Some precautions you can take are as follows:

- Don't connect the VM to your local network
- Don't mount host folders or disks to the VM
- Disable host-VM interfaces such as shared folders

You may find this guide useful: https://zeltser.com/build-malware-analysis-toolkit/